# Officially stuck, need to convert link with the "Heavy Black Heart" unicode character across domains

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, unicode, newsletter

A client had sent out a mass email using Constant Contact and all the links contained the unicode text character "Heavy Black Heart", all the available formats can be seen here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2764/index.htm:

So the Constant Contact Mail Out has links that all similar to the following

```
http://www.wordpress.com/events/❤-heart-card-event-at-kendra-scott
```

They link to a 404 as they are parsed by Constant Contacts Engine and when clicked from the newsletter go through Constant Contact and become the following:

```
http://www.wordpress/event/&#x2764;-heart-card-event-christofle-2
```

So...

Because we cannot un-send the newsletter and Constant Contact is well a Constant,  I'm stuck with trying to convert the Unicode heart from the unicode heart, back to the unicode heart after being parsed by Constant Contact.

Things I've Tried:

1.Changing the slug of the the event/post in wordpress, wordpress will not recognize the html &#x2764 and just ignores it upon saving.

2.Changing the slug link of the post/event to a%c2%9d%c2%a4 (the hex version escaped) for the heart, no good, it still comes out using the ❤ in and sending to a 404;

3.Trying to use the .htaccess mode_rewrites file to grab the html version of the url and redirect it to the Unicode hex version (really thought this would do it) nope, it still loads and directs to the good ol 404.

4.Using the strange already parsed resulting characters ( the A, big O, little O) in the slug, this one actually took and altered the slugs but still did not link to the url from the newsletter.

So now i'm just spinning wheels and still need the newsletter to link to the proper post/event page. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Just a note:  My client thought the heart inside of a url would be cool and sent the letter by copying and pasting directly into the Constant Contact form.  I'm assuming that CC takes the link and parses it using it's own system and then rebuilding the link for tracking so as far as I can tell, linking with a Unicode Text Character is a big "Do Not Try" no-one informed them of.

If the newsletter had not already been sent this would be a snap to fix but since it's already out, the only thing I can do is try and find a way to direct the links to the right wordpress posts/events.

Comment: Have you tried %E2 %9D %A4 (the UTF-8 encoding)?

Comment: Tried it, Constant Contact would take and convert it into an HTML element (#0x2764;) version. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is the fact that anything after (and including) the hash is not sent to the server. So, in actual fact, your server sees the following URL request:

```
http://www.your-domain.com/event/&
```

So if you're trying to do a htaccess redirect, something like this should work:

```
Redirect /event/& /event/❤-heart-card-event-christofle-2
```

Or, if you can, I'd recommend removing the heart from the permalink and instead doing this:

```
Redirect /event/& /event/heart-card-event-christofle-2
```

Comment: Christian, great suggestion.  I was only able to use it to re-direct to one link ( there were five all together ) on the calendar, but it got me past the 404.  Thanks for the advice.